# Adding GCM to android eclipse project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to add push notifications to my android application and I found [this tutorial on the topic](http://youtube.com/watch?v=Vd8bIkE29U4).

But eclipse does not recognize `GoogleCoundMessaging`, even though I added `google_play_service_lib` to my project.

Here is [my captured screen](http://www.4shared.com/download/yOS7ttUEce/Capture.PNG?lgfp=3000)

Comment: Aside from your question, you should be using android-studio as your IDE

Comment: maybe you should type "GoogleCloudMessaging" instead of "GoogleCoundMessaging"

Comment: you have to add Jar file for C2DM and GCM in lib folder.

Comment: @Kushan2 Can I find C2DM and GCM jar files in my sdk folder?

Comment: no,you have to download and put in lib folder

Comment: @Kushan2 Can you please send a link to download latest JAR file?

Comment: for GCM :: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgcmjar.htm                                  for C2DM  :: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadc2dmjar.htm

Comment: have you set the classpath of your library??

Comment: @Nawaf how to set class path in eclipse?

Comment: visit : [link](http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/44)

Comment: Have you done ? @HashaŋSachiŋtha

Answer (score 0):

**I have fixed my problem.**

*I added "google_play service.jar" to my project "libs" folder and add it to project build path.

*Then eclipse recognized "GoogleCloudMessaging"

*But application stop working when try to get GCM RegID.

*I run my application without debugging. All problems fixed!